# php 8.2.2 not logging syntax errors to error log defined in php.ini

Tags: php

Server: AlmaLinux 8, PHP 8.2.2

I have many servers with variety of PHP versions, on most the code below logs correctly to the specified error log file. The server I have a problem with was just upgraded to PHP 8.2.2.

I have in my php.ini

```
// I have tried a variety of settings
error_reporting = E_ALL
log_errors = On
display_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
error_log = /var/log/php
```

I have a bit of code (just the important bits)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('error_log','/var/log/php');
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);

// debug message
error_log("start of script");

// removed the error handling in the code
// the connection works, I know!
$MJCONN = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($MJCONN, $database);

// many lines of code deleted

if(!$result = mysqli_query($MJCONN, $TheQuery)) {
  error_log("It's dead Jim");
  exit;
}

// many lines of code deleted

// here is my error, I mispelled the variable name
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulr))
{
  // some code here
} 
?>
```

The debug message using error_log("start of script") is correctly shown in the file, so this is NOT a permission error.

Whatever I try, the mispelled variable name error is never displayed in the log file. I even tried to mispell a function name, same nothing is displayed in the error_log file.

If I set this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log','/var/log/php');
```

It works correctly and the error is displayed on the screen, which is NOT what I want.
I want syntax - or preferably all errors - logged in the error_log.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check which `php.ini` configure file was loaded by PHP 8.2.2,
You can used command line to check the `php.ini` file used :

```
$ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Turns out php-fpm has changed their core config file www.conf. It now comes default with a setting 'php_admin_value[error_log]' overriding the 'error_log' file in php.ini also overruling (absolute) "ini_set(error_log)". It also stuffs up the formatting.

Comment: Yes, If you use php-fpm, the configuration setted by php-fpm.conf would be overwrited those in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the default config file for php-fpm has changed.
It now comes with a default setting

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

The problem with this it absolute overrides ini_set, so the following code

```
ini_set('error_log','/var/log/php')
```

has no meaning anywhere in your code.

If you comment out this code like so

```
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

the setting in php.ini takes over again, but the error formatting is in shambles, the only way to fix all of this it to

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

to get it well formatted back to the original location, but ini_set will still not work.